# How to get RTF from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

How do I get the text in RTF of a `RichTextBox`? I'm trying to get like this, but the property does not exist.

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
string s = rtb.Rtf;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get the actual XAML created by the user inside of the RichTextBox:

```
   TextRange tr = new TextRange(myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                                myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Xaml);
   string xamlText = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

EDIT: I don't have code in front of me to test, but an instance of the `TextRange` type has a `Save` (to stream) method that takes a `DataFormats` parameter, which can be `DataFormats.Rtf`

Comment: DataFormats contains a Rtf member. Perhaps this method will work.

Comment: And now, how do I can set the RTF text of a RichTextBox?

Comment: Couple things: 1)  I recommend adding a `using` around your `MemoryStream` -- technically it implements `IDisposable`, though it doesn't appear that it will cause a memory leak if you omit it. 2) You are correct, `tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);` is what you need for RTF data (the XAML is interesting, but it's not RTF). Also, for readers doing this to copy data into the clipboard, use `Clipboard.SetText(rtfText, TextDataFormat.Rtf)`

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 RichTextBox classes, one from the winforms framework and one from the WPF framework:

```
System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox wpfBox;
System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox winformsBox;
```

Only the Winforms RichTextBox has an Rtf property, the other has a Document property which contains a FlowDocument.

Comment: Yes I know...

From the Document property, how do I get the RTF text?

Comment: You should look at converting a FlowDocument to an RTF string because the contents of the WPF control is a FlowDocument and not RTF. I have no idea how to accomplish this though.